# Python: Large dataset where API function is applied to every row, would a batch function to apply it groups improve performance?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, function

I'm working with the Google Maps Geocodinng API and have a list of cities (>13k) that I need to look up to return the coordinates

This is slow. I have a test batch of 100 rows and it takes >1 minute

I was wondering whether it's better performance to have a function that groups the rows into batches of 10, then applies the Google lookup function to those groups:

```
def batcher(sequence, batch_size):
    return (sequence[position:position + batch_size] for position in range(0, 
    len(sequence), batch_size))

for group in batcher(data['ghana_city'], 10):
    data['geocode_result'] = data['ghana_city'].map(gmaps.geocode)
```

Over simply

```
data['geocode_result'] = data['ghana_city'].map(gmaps.geocode)
```

The reason being that the first would perform the call on a batch of 10 rows, whereas the second on the entire lot of rows

In more detail, what this code is doing is looking up the coordinates on Google Maps for whatever is entered in the column ghana_city

The issue i'm having is performance

[image]

The Google API is limited to 2500 results per day, but i've found that it times out if my batches are greater in size than about 250 rows

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks

Comment: I am not entirely sure, what you are asking here: You're firing off one HTTP request per address under the hood, right? So what exactly are you trying to "batch up"?

Comment: Sometimes if the call to the Google API takes too long, it times out. My idea was to create a batcher function that basically calls the Google API in batches of 10. I suppose i'm asking if this works or if there is a better approach

Comment: I still think, the API works in a way, that one HTTP request is one coordinate being looked up. So I guess the only way to "bundle" them up, is squeezing them into the same TCP connection. I am not sure how you would do that with your current setup though.